# assign mapped value to input string

Tags: java, hashmap

I am not able to get the value of the string i have entered according to my mapped values??
I want the value which i want to get as 8118198920

```
import java.util.*;

class maptable1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> hm =
                new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        hm.put("A", Integer.valueOf(1));
        hm.put("B", Integer.valueOf(2));
        hm.put("C", Integer.valueOf(3));
        hm.put("D", Integer.valueOf(4));
        hm.put("E", Integer.valueOf(5));
        hm.put("F", Integer.valueOf(6));
        hm.put("G", Integer.valueOf(7));
        hm.put("H", Integer.valueOf(8));
        hm.put("I", Integer.valueOf(9));
        hm.put("J", Integer.valueOf(10));
        hm.put("K", Integer.valueOf(11));
        hm.put("L", Integer.valueOf(12));
        hm.put("M", Integer.valueOf(13));
        hm.put("N", Integer.valueOf(14));
        hm.put("O", Integer.valueOf(15));
        hm.put("P", Integer.valueOf(16));
        hm.put("Q", Integer.valueOf(17));
        hm.put("R", Integer.valueOf(18));
        hm.put("S", Integer.valueOf(19));
        hm.put("T", Integer.valueOf(20));
        hm.put("U", Integer.valueOf(21));
        hm.put("V", Integer.valueOf(22));
        hm.put("W", Integer.valueOf(23));
        hm.put("X", Integer.valueOf(24));
        hm.put("Y", Integer.valueOf(25));
        hm.put("Z", Integer.valueOf(26));

        System.out.println("The Value is: " + hm.get("HARSHIT"));
    }
}
```

Comment: value for key `HARSHIT` is not exist

Answer (score 1):

Hash maps don't work like that.

To produce what you want, you need to call `hm.get()` with each character in the string, convert the integer you get to a string, and join all of these strings together.

One way to implement this is to use streams:

```
// "s" is a string variable containing "HARSHIT"
String result = s.chars().mapToObj(x -> Character.toString((char)x))
        .map(x -> Integer.toString(hm.get(x)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Also note that you don't need `Integer.valueOf`. You can just use the integer itself.